# Highly distorted sound on stereo but headphone gives perfect output

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa, headphones, spotify

I am struggling with the audio output of my laptop that's running 12.04 LTS. It was all fine till yesterday. I played the spotify in the web player and abruptly the sound just reduced and I couldnt hear anything on the stereo. On the other hand, when I connect the headphone , the sound is just perfect. I have the following configuration:-

- HP PROBOOK 6450b,
- Codec: IDT 92HD75B3X5
- Codec: LSI ID 1040
- Codec: Intel IbexPeak HDMI